# выдает ошибку в строке screen.blit(bg(0,0))

Tags: python, pygame

код:

```py
import pygame
import random

from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("space.ogg")
mixer.music.play()

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

# Задаем цвета


bg = pygame.image.load('galaxy.jpg')

black = (0, 0, 0)

# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Шутер")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('rocket.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.x = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        ks = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if ks[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x = -8
        if ks[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x = 8
            self.rect.x += self.x
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()

all_sprites.add(player)


running = True

while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update()
    
    screen.blit(bg(0,0))

    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    bg.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что пытаетесь вызвать функцию bg как функцию, но на самом деле bg является загруженным изображением. Решить можно заменив строку screen.blit(bg(0,0)) на screen.blit(bg, (0,0)), чтобы нарисовать загруженное изображение на экране

```
import random
import pygame
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("space.ogg")
mixer.music.play()

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

# Задаем цвета
bg = pygame.image.load('galaxy.jpg')
black = (0, 0, 0)

# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Шутер")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('rocket.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.x = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        ks = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if ks[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x = -8
        if ks[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x = 8
            self.rect.x += self.x
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

running = True

while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update()
    
    screen.blit(bg, (0,0))

    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, помогло. правда чет посты дизлайкают хотя вроде все норм расписал((

Comment: @exception Видимо потому, что саму ошибку вы в вопросе не приложили и никакого текста не написали в вопросе, только код. Ну, я предполагаю.

Comment: @exception дело в том, что вопрос был создан, по сути, из-за одной пропущенной запятой

Answer (score 1):

При передаче аргументов в функцию screen.blit(bg(0,0)) пропущена запятая. :)